# NoMethodError in CalendarPosts#index undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass... error only sometimes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, null, nomethoderror

Rails newbie.. I'm getting an error on my join table index page.. but only sometimes. I'm confused since sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Also when I go into pry and search for what is throwing the error, the item is there.

join table relationship:
post has many calendars/calendars has many posts
calendars_posts belongs_to calendars
calendar_posts belongs_to posts

calendar_posts controller:

```
  def index
@calendars = current_user.calendars
```

end

index.html.erb:

```
   <h1>Scheduled Posts</h1>

<% current_user.calendars.each do |calendar| %>
<h2> <%= calendar.name %> </h2>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th>Link</th>
      <th>Picture</th>
      <th>Platforms</th>
      <th>Finalized</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% calendar.calendar_posts.each do |calendar_post| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= calendar_post.post.title.titleize %> </td>
      <td>  <%= calendar_post.date%> </td>
      <td><%= calendar_post.time %></td>
      <td>  <%= calendar_post.post.content %> </td>
      <td>  <%= calendar_post.post.link %> </td>
      <td>  <%= image_tag(calendar_post.post.picture_url, width: 200) if calendar_post.post.picture.present? %> </td>
      <td>
        <% calendar_post.post.platforms.each do |platform| %>
        <%= platform.name.titleize %> <br>
        <% end %>
      </td>
      <td>  <%= human_boolean(calendar_post.post.finalized) %> </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<% end %>
```

I'm just confused because the error only happens sometimes... But once it starts happening then it happens every time I try to access the page after? Is there something I can do to ward off against nil?

Comment: for every `calendar_post` for which `post` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

I understand people are voting this down but I always do my research before posting and I finally figured out the issue. It was not like any of the other issues that showed up in related searches so it may be helpful for others to know... In my models I had Calendar and Posts with a join table CalendarPosts with user submittable attributes of time and date. The user can create a post and it floats separately from everything because I wanted someone to be able to jot ideas down as a "filler" and not be required to go further than that. This nil:nilclass error was coming from the fact that I had a dependency problem.  My calendar_posts are dependent on posts. But I didn't have a dependency destroy in my post or calendar models. If a user deletes a post, the calendar post still existed but the post did not, which was the issue. Adding in the dependency destroy fixed my problem.